# Bat File to Delete Files depending on name

Tags: file, batch-file, file-extension

I have some software that monitors transactions on our ERP system, when it fails to update the system with the new transaction it generates an error and creates a PDF of the transaction document for every 30 minutes that the error persists.

the naming conventions go like this: **AINA00001** is the original transaction document, when its updated but an error occurs a PDF is created called **AINA00001-1** and then another one will become **AINA00001-2**.

Because of recently upgrading the system there have been a lot of errors being generated for the system. I wanted to write a .bat file so that it deletes the files that are between the original document and the last document created for it and I would be able to run the document weekly. so if AINA00001 had 30 errors I could delete AINA00001-1 and AINA00001-29 and everything in between those.

Comment: You don't need a batch file.  You need wildcard characters.

Answer (score 1):

From the given information, you should be good with simply doing:

```
DEL AINA*-*
```

This will delete all files starting with `AINA` and containing a dash `-` later on, i.e. the "original transaction document" like `AINA00001` will not be deleted. I'd recommend trying it out with this first:

```
DIR /B AINA*-*
```

This will output the files that would be deleted by the first command.

Comment: Hi, Very useful but unfortunately I wanted to keep the last entry of the error made. So if AINA00001 had 30 errors I could delete AINA00001-1 and AINA00001-29 and everything in between those two entries.